Instalación de un app Lavarel
Estoy intentando instalar una app que compre en una web nueva. Sin embargo aunque las instrucciones son sencillas me topo en un paso de base de datos.
Ya cargue los archivos. Si alguien quiere hacer de freelancer y guiarme con la instalación en una llamada lo puedo pagar.
No es nada complicado.

Mejor usa alguna plataforma de freelancers para eso, tipo Upwork o freelance o fiverr.  O si te quieres ahorrar dinero explica mejor y con más detalle que te ocurre a ver si alguien te ayuda aqui mismo, pero tal como has formulado tu pregunta actual no es válida para este sitio, lo siento.

Si compraste, deberias tener soporte, no?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
